# How to get multiple possible solutions for differential evolution algorithm?

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, scipy, differential-evolution

the tutorial from scipy only shows one possible solution for differential evolution (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html).

How can i get multiple solutions? And if not, is it because of scipy implementation or are differential evolutions algorithm just designed that way?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import rosen, differential_evolution
bounds = [(0,2), (0, 2), (0, 2), (0, 2), (0, 2)]
result = differential_evolution(rosen, bounds)
result.x, result.fun
```

Comment: Set a different seed should give you a different solution. `differential_evolution(rosen, bounds, seed=42)` and `differential_evolution(rosen, bounds, seed=24)`

Answer (score 0):

There are several hyperparameters that you can set for the evolution algorithm to diverge.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html

E.g.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import rosen, differential_evolution
bounds = [(0,2), (1, 3), (1, 2), (4, 7), (500, 900)]

result = differential_evolution(rosen, bounds, seed=234)
print(result.x, result.fun)

result = differential_evolution(rosen, bounds, seed=42)
print(result.x, result.fun)

result = differential_evolution(rosen, bounds, seed=42)
print(result.x, result.fun)

result = differential_evolution(rosen, bounds, seed=23, mutation=(0.9, 1), recombination=0.8)
print(result.x, result.fun)

result = differential_evolution(rosen, bounds, seed=23, maxiter=2, mutation=(0.9, 1), recombination=0.8)
print(result.x, result.fun)

result = differential_evolution(rosen, bounds, seed=23, maxiter=2, mutation=(0.9, 1), recombination=0.8)
print(result.x, result.fun)
```

[out]:

```
(array([  1.1880044 ,   1.41300298,   2.        ,   7.        ,
        500.        ]),
 20341037.207360283)

(array([  1.18838044,   1.41362179,   2.        ,   7.        ,
        500.        ]),
 20341037.207038924)
​
(array([  1.18891057,   1.41438122,   2.        ,   7.        ,
        500.        ]),
 20341037.207497682)

(array([  1.1885353 ,   1.41414795,   2.        ,   7.        ,
        500.        ]),
 20341037.207302164)
```

---

##### Having a large variance in the bounds

But since rosen function is formulaic, the variance in the bounds needs to be large enough to see significant changes in the results.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import rosen, differential_evolution
bounds = [(0,221529234), (123121, 31231232), (1231, 291231235), (30434, 1232317), (500, 900)]

result = differential_evolution(rosen, bounds, seed=234)
print(result.x, result.fun)

result = differential_evolution(rosen, bounds, seed=42)
print(result.x, result.fun)
```

[out]:

```
(array([  8141.41766062, 123121.        ,   1231.        ,  30434.        ,
           813.59702423]),
 2.3065086995396433e+22)

(array([     0.        , 123121.        ,   3838.30391681,  30434.        ,
           881.09558529]),
 2.30646627657552e+22)
```

Comment: I should have clarified that my the function i am using, is more complex and it takes far longer to get the optimum, wichi is why running multiple searches is not a valid option for me.

Comment: There's no easy way to get around running multiple seeds or multiple hyperparameters unless you do something like bandits, take a look at https://optuna.org/#code_examples . 

But if you want the output of different generations, simply iterate through the different maxiter.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one global minimum in the `rosen` function. It's not clear why you expect there to be multiple solutions. `differential_evolution` is designed to have a greater probability of finding that global minimum.
If you have a solution with multiple minima and you want to record them all then `shgo` might be your best option. Alternatively you could track the progress of the differential_evolution population to identify different minima in the energy surface.

Comment: I was asking because someone said that when using genetic algorithms, you could output not only the best optimum found, but the whole last generation.

Comment: By the last generation the population should've converged on a solution, so there won't be much variation. It's possible to record every generation, but it's a little involved. As I said above, if you want to record the multiple local minimas you should use `shgo`.